# ASP.NET MVC Razor, generate profile using url /profile/{username}

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to create user profiles based on url.
I know how to get paramaters from url like www.domain.com/profile?id=username
But I would like to keep it SEO friendly and instead get value from url format: 
www.domain.com/profile/username

I am using MVC Razor from Visual Studio 2017 and disgarded MSSQL database, instead implemented MySQL with a user table.

My thoughts how it should work.
User visits web page www.domain.com/profile/user235

the server loads up the controller and gets the input "user235"

the controller sends the input to the .cshtml page and the .cshtml page performs 
query to the MySQL database getting the user data array and filling the page with the data.

Is my thoughts correct? Any advice or suggestions how I should handle this?

**EDIT: Found the solution at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/routing/creating-readable-urls-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites**

@UrlData[0].ToString()

This will get any value after / in razor pages
example: 
profile.cshtml has string username = @UrlData[0].ToString()

www.domain.com/profile/John

@UrlData[0].ToString() = "John"

If you want something like www.domain.com/profile/John/blog43

string username = @UrlData[0].ToString()
string blogid = @UrlData[1].ToString()

And with this information you can query the database to get information...
Make sure to validate the username and blog input for any kind of sql injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a route definition to get seo friendly urls like that

Here is how you do it with attribute routing

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    [Route("Profile/{userId}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string userId)
    {
        return Content("Proile for " + userId);
    }
}
```

So when you user access `/yourSite/profile/scott` the Index action of Profile controller will be executed and the username value from the url (scott) will be available in the userId parameter of the action method. Here i am simply returning a string "Profile for scott". But you can udpate it to query your database to get the corresponding record and pass that information to a view using a view model.

If you are using Razor pages, you will create a Profile page and it's model and specify the route

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model ProfileModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";
}    
<h3>@Model.Message</h3>
```

And in your `Profile.cshtml.cs`

```
public class ProfileModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(string id)
    {
        Message = "Profile of "+ id;
    }
}
```

Like i mentioned above, i am just printing a string with the passed username from the url. But you can change it to get your data from your db table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am not sure what MVC version I am using but I am unable to add controller only a Web API Controller Class (v2.1). Upon using your code it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: What you mean by you are unable to add a controller ? If you use Visual studio , you can right click and add a new class. What is stopping you ?

Comment: I am new to ASP.NET and chose the default MVC Razor template, there is no Controller folder and doesn't let me add a controller. I can add .cs classes in App_Code thought. but will it recognize it as a controller and load it?

Comment: So you are not using an asp.mvc app, but using razor pages ?

Comment: Visual Studio > New > Web site > ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v3).

Comment: I posted an update to the answer to handle how to do it in RazorPages

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working using your code, but I get the general concept now. I will do some more research and figure it out :) Thank you! +1

Comment: I found a solution and updated my post to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you, please have a look https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/07/21/generating-route-urls-in-asp-net-core-mvc