# How can I pass username as parameter in url within Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

**This is my method in `cshtml`**:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string username)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        username = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }
}
```

I added in `cshtml` at the top the parameter like `@page "{username?}"`

I want to redirect the user to `www.domainname.com/IndexUser?username=usernameparam`.
How can I do this? I looked everywhere and can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to `return Redirect($"www.domainname.com/IndexUser?username={username}");` instead of `return Page();`?

Comment: This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: return Redirect seems like it doesn't work for razor pages

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same page that is calling `OnGetAsync(string username)` method?

Comment: I have a login class where it's called like this: return LocalRedirect($"~/Identity/UserExperience/IndexUser?username={user.UserName}");

Comment: I just want that my IndexUser always add the url parameter everytime is loaded.. been searching for 2 hours on the internet how to fix this

Comment: Could you please share those parts of your code?

Comment: var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                    var emailConfirmed = await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Welcome!");
                        return LocalRedirect($"~/Identity/UserExperience/IndexUser?username={user.UserName}");
                    }

Comment: Can this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894826/asp-net-mvc-razor-generate-profile-using-url-profile-username help you?

Comment: no.. when I return Page() it's the problem.. I don't know how to return Page + "?username=myparamusername". I already know how to do what that guy was showing there

Comment: in my application when i click login it generates the correct link return LocalRedirect($"~/Identity/UserExperience/IndexUser?username={user.UserName}"); but when I refresh the IndexUser page is loading without the parameter

Comment: Sorry, I will again share a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693364/asp-net-core-2-1-razor-page-return-page-with-model that might help, which suggests to set your Page Model's property before `return Page()`. In your case, I am assuming your page model has `username` property, you can set it.

Comment: If the above link doesn't solve your issue, please put your related codes(cshtml, controller, page model etc...) to the question part in a readable format, so that we can reproduce it.